# Extjs 4 updateRecord error

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

*(Sorry in advance if the post is to long, I just add all the code that is involved in the problem, then I think it could be easier to get an answer)*

Hello, I'm encountering a problem when I try to update a store in extjs 4.

To back up a little I'm developing a general grid where you can send the columns you need and also a the fields in a window to add new rows to the grid, then this is the **general grid**:

```
Ext.define('masterDataGridControls', {
        extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        id : 'panelWin',
        windowItems : null,
        addWin : null,

        initComponent : function() {
            var me = this;

            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                        dockedItems : [{
                            xtype : 'toolbar',
                            dock : 'top',
                            items : [{
                                        xtype : 'button',
                                        id : 'btn_delete',
                                        iconCls : 'deleteIcon',
                                        tooltip : 'Delete row or group',
                                        handler : function() {
                                            var selection = me.getView()
                                                    .getSelectionModel()
                                                    .getSelection()[0];
                                            if (selection) {
                                                store.remove(selection);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        xtype : 'button',
                                        id : 'btn_add',
                                        iconCls : 'addIcon',
                                        tooltip : 'Add row or group',
                                        handler : me.addToList
                                    }]
                        }]
                    });

            me.callParent(arguments);
        },

        getAddWindow : function() {
            if (!this.addWin) {
                this.addWin = new windowPop({
                            formItems : this.windowItems,
                            idParent : this.config.id,
                            record : this.store.model.prototype
                        });
            }
            return this.addWin;
        },

        addToList : function() {
            var addWindow = this.findParentByType().findParentByType()
                    .getAddWindow();;
            addWindow.show();
        }
    });
```

And I have the class **windowPop** that is the one who receives the fields, display them and save the data:

```
Ext.define("windowPop", {
extend : "Ext.window.Window",
formPanel : null,
formItems : null,
record : null,
idParent : null,

initComponent : function() {
    var me = this;

    me.formPanel = new Ext.form.Panel({
                items : this.formItems,
                layout: 'anchor'
            });

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
                resizable : false,
                closable : false,
                width : 300,
                minWidth : 300,
                minHeight : 200,
                y : 150,
                layout : 'fit',
                plain : true,
                modal : true,
                items : [me.formPanel],
                buttons : [{
                            text : "i_Save",
                            handler : function() {
                                console.info(me.record);
                                me.formPanel.getForm().updateRecord(me.record);
                                Ext.getCmp(me.idParent).fireEvent("winSave",me.record);
                                me.formPanel.getForm().reset();
                                me.hide();
                            }
                        }, {
                            text : 'i_Cancel',
                            handler : function() {
                             me.formPanel.getForm().reset();
                                me.hide();
                            }
                        }]
            });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

And I have my **specific grid**, where I define a data.model and for now I'm using a fixed store, but later on will be replace by the one I get from the server:

```
Ext.define('userKeys', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : [{
                    name : 'text',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    name : 'description',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    name : 'group',
                    type : 'string'
                }]
    });

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'userKeys',
        data : [{
                    text : "que mamera",
                    description : "asdfasdf",
                    group : 'homework'
                }, {
                    text : "book report",
                    description : 'hola',
                    group : 'homework'
                }, {
                    text : "alegebra",
                    description : "haha",
                    group : 'homework'
                }, {
                    text : "buy lottery tickets",
                    description : "kajsdf",
                    group : 'homework'
                }]

    });


Ext.define('ConfigInterfacesUserKeys', {
        extend : 'masterDataGridControls',

        initComponent : function() {
            var me = this;

            me.columns = [{
                        id : 'cl_input',
                        header : 'i_Text',
                        dataIndex : 'text',
                        width : 220
                    }, {
                        header : 'i_Description',
                        dataIndex : 'description',
                        width : 130
                    }, {
                        header : 'i_group',
                        dataIndex : 'group',
                        width : 130
                    }];

            me.windowItems = [{
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        id : 'txt_sendTime',
                        fieldLabel : 'text',
                        margin : '5 0 0 5',
                        style : 'font-weight:bold',
                        labelWidth : 120,
                        name : 'text'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        id : 'txt_waitTime',
                        fieldLabel : 'description',
                        margin : '5 0 0 5',
                        style : 'font-weight:bold',
                        labelWidth : 120,
                        name : 'description'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        id : 'txt_group',
                        fieldLabel : 'group',
                        margin : '5 0 0 5',
                        style : 'font-weight:bold',
                        labelWidth : 120,
                        name : 'group'
                    }];

            me.store = store;

            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    })
```

**The Problem**

When I try to save the fields as you see in the windowPop class Im doing this:

```
me.formPanel.getForm().updateRecord(me.record);
```

But I get the next error:

```
this[this.persistenceProperty] is undefined
```

I tracked down the error and I find that all start when in the function **updateRecord** try to set the object to the store:

```
updateRecord: function(record) {
    var fields = record.fields,
    values = this.getFieldValues(),
    name,
    obj = {};
    fields.each(function(f) {
        name = f.name;
        if (name in values) {
            obj[name] = values[name];
        }
    });
    record.beginEdit();
    **record.set(obj);**
    record.endEdit();
    return this;
}
```

I don't know if it is something wrong when I **send the model** to the **window** from the **general grid**, I sent it this way:

```
record : this.store.model.prototype
```

Then I'm not sure if its because the model I'm sending its not well forme.

I've been searching the internet but I can't find a proper answer then it will be really helpful if you can guide me in the right way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know if it is something wrong when I send the model to the
>   window from the general grid

I believe it is. You are sending not an empty instance (which should be sent) but a class' prototype. Try to send:

```
record : new this.store.model()
```

Comment: It worked :), then the problem was because I was sending an already fill object, what I should had send the model but empty... thanks a lot :)...